# finding a list in a list of list based on one element

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of lists representing a connectivity graph in Python. This list look like a n*2 matrix

```
example = [[1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 8], [2, 1], [2, 9], [2,5] ]
```

what I want to do is to find the value of the first elements of the lists where the second element is equal to a user defined value. For instance :

- input 1 returns [2] (because [2,1])
- input 5 returns  [1,2] (because [1,5] and [2,5])
- input 7 returns []

in Matlab, I could use

```
output = example(example(:,1)==input, 2);
```

but I would like to do this in Python (in the most pythonic and efficient way)

Comment: The most efficient way would be to use numpy. It's also very much like Matlab matrices as it is based on a very similar class `Numpy.Array`.

Comment: You have to accept one of the answers, if that was useful for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as a filter, like this

```
>>> example = [[1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 8], [2, 1], [2, 9], [2,5]]
>>> n = 5
>>> [first for first, second in example if second == n]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the Python functions map and filter very comfortable:

```
>>> example = [[1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 8], [2, 1], [2, 9], [2,5] ]
>>> n = 5
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: n in x, example))
[1,2]
```

With lambda you can define anonyme functions...
Syntax:

```
lambda arg0,arg1...: e
```

arg0,arg1... are your parameters of the fucntion, and e is the expression.
They use lambda functions mostly in functions like map, reduce, filter etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
exemple = [[1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 8], [2, 1], [2, 9], [2,5] ]
foundElements = []
** input = [...] *** List of Inputs
for item in exemple:
    if item[1] in input :
        foundElements.append(item[0])
```